# create an abstract class from which bass class will be derived c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have to make a base class with one derived class in C++. In the end I need to evidence polymorphism between 2 methodes void Read and void Show.

After I did this, I have to create an abstract class Object from which the base class will be derived.This class will contain just pure virtual methods Read and Show.

I don't think I fully understand this. So I make an abstract class Object where I put these 2 methods with "=0" to mke them pure. But this means that I have to edit the base class also, to make it derived from class Object? Like, before:

```
class Base {

}
```

after

```
Class Base : public Object
```

Can someone make me understand?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. In your `Base` class, you can mark methods `virtual` that you intend to be polymorphic. You can set the functions `= 0` if they are "pure virtual" and have no implementation in the base class, and are required in any concrete derived class.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Read() = 0;
    virtual void Show() = 0;
};
```

Then for your derived class you had the syntax backwards. Note that the `override` keyword indicates that you are overriding a virtual method from the base class. This keyword enforces that the function signature matches the one from a base class.

```
class Object : public Base
{
public:
    void Read() override;   // implement this
    void Show() override;   // implement this
};
```

The usage could look like the following. Note that you instantiate an `Object` but carry a pointer to a `Base*`. Due to polymorphism, the derived implementations are invoked.

```
int main()
{
    Object obj;
    Base* p = &obj;
    p->Read();  // due to polymorphism will call Object::Read
    p->Show();  // due to polymorphism will call Object::Show
}
```